# Get rid of the word private in bbpress forums names

Tags: bbpress, forum

When I declare a forum private the word "private:" is prepend to the title of the forum, and is visible even for the register members.

how can I get rid of that prepend word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR BBPress relies on WP functions with these titles, so most probably this will be helpful:

```
function remove_private_prefix_from_title( $title ) {
    return '%s';
}
add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'remove_private_prefix_from_title' );
```

And here you can find docs for that filter: [`private_title_format`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/private_title_format)

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, but, in which file this function should be in? in the functions.php of the theme?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in functions.php file